# how does the object parameter with render work exactly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what does the following code do?

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
....
<% end %>
```

It renders a partial name _error_messages.html.erb in app/views/shared but what does the object parameter exactly do? and f.object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/):

```
render(options = {}, locals = {}, &block)
```

> If no options hash is passed or :update specified, the default is to
>   render a partial and use the second parameter as the locals hash.

So, `object` is a local variable that will be used in the partial, and `f.object` is the value of the variable.

For more info, read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with what the object method in "f.object" does, but in terms of "object:"

according to the [Rails API: Action View Partials](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

> By default ActionView::PartialRenderer doesn’t have any local
>   variables. The :object option can be used to pass an object to the
>   partial. For instance:
>
> <%= render partial: "account", object: @buyer %> would provide the
>   @buyer object to the partial, available under the local variable
>   account